# How to set views configurations settings on custom module install?

Tags: views, 8, configuration

I have a custom module. On its installation I want to set some configuration settings of views like:

```
ui.show.master_display
ui.show.sql_query.enabled
```

to `TRUE`.

For this I have added a file `mymod_views.settings.yml` to `modules/mymod/config/install/`.
the content of the file is:

```
ui:
  show:
    additional_queries: true
    advanced_column: true
    master_display: true
    performance_statistics: true
    preview_information: true
    sql_query:
      enabled: true
      where: above
    display_embed: false
  always_live_preview: false
```

But on the installation of the module I am getting the following exception.

```
exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException' with message 'Configuration objects (mymod_views.settings) provided by mymod already
exist in active configuration' in
/var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/PreExistingConfigException.php:70
```

Can someone tells me how I will set these options through my module?

Comment: Check out [Install fails with PreExistingConfigException](https://www.drupal.org/node/2461341).

Comment: It does not have any answer to my question

Comment: Related: [How to override configuration from a file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/187476/1908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change or override configuration from other modules like that, you can only provide new, not yet existing configuration in `config/install`. The only exception to that rule are install profiles.

Instead, you need to implement `hook_install()` and alter the configuration there. See `locale_install()` for example:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()
  ->getEditable('views_ui.settings')
  ->set('ui.show.master_display', TRUE)
  ->save();
```